# SMTP nodemailer, works in localhost not in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, nodemailer

I deployed an application to the free tier of Heroku, using nodemailer i setup an option in the app for me to receive some `JSON` from a form, and use that information to email myself, in localhost, this works fine, ive tested it extensively to be sure that it would work, but when i went to test this in production i found that it is only returning a 400 bad request, this is the status code, i return on something going wrong in the server logic.

```
/*
  @Desc:   Allows a user to send a support email
  @Route:  POST /api/support
  @access: Public
*/
export const sendSupportMail = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const message =
    `Name: ${req.body.name} \n` +
    `Email: ${req.body.email} \n` +
    `Phone: ${req.body.phone} \n` +
    `Message: ${req.body.message} \n`;
  try {
    await sendEmail({
      email: process.env.SUPPORT_EMAIL,
      subject: `Support Email`,
      message: message,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, error });
  }
});
```

This all worked in localhost, I've been looking around on the net, and im pretty sure this is an issue because of the free-tier hosting of heroku, however before i commit myself to upgrading the tier, id like to try to fix it before hand or atleast get a good explanation of why this isnt working.

Comment: Did you allow the access to your Google Account

Comment: @Rahul its a `hotmail` account, and yes i setup less secure apps, interesting enough, i can send emails using the password reset functionality i implemented in the app, that works fine, but it wont work for the support page.